Page not found (404) django. Ошибка при переходе на страницу, на которой должна отобразиться подробная информация о товаре из бд
я новичок в Django. Пишу сайт онлайн доски объявлений. При нажатии на карточку товара, по идее должна отобразиться страница с подробной информацией о нём, которая берётся из базы данных, но выходит ошибка "Page not found (404)". Помогите разобраться. Вот фрагменты кода:
models.py
from django.db import models
class Products(models.Model):
title = models.TextField()
description = models.TextField()
price = models.IntegerField()

views.py
from .models import Products
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
def index(request):
prod = Products.objects.all()
return render(request, 'index.html', context = {'prod' : prod}) 
def product_detail(request, product_id):
product = Products.objects.get(id=product_id)
product = get_object_or_404(product, id=product_id)
return render(request, 'product_detail.html', {'product': product})

urls.py
from test_app import views
urlpatterns = [
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
path('', views.index, name = 'index'),
path('index.html', views.index, name = 'index'),
path('product/<int:product_id>/', views.product_detail, name='product_detail'),
]

product_detail.html
index.html
Ошибка

Добро пожаловать на сайт ru.SO!
Вопросы по теме, которые тем не менее не стоит задавать:=>
Поиск ошибок, которые нельзя воспроизвести =>https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic
удалите картинки
https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%83%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b4%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b4%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%88%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2

ошибка происходит из-за того, что в массиве urlpatterns в файле urls.py нет пути, по которому вы переходите.
Ошибка находится в файле index.html:
<div class="card-body">
    <a href="product_detail.html" class="h3 text-decoration-none">{{ prod.title }}</a>
    <p class="mb-0">{{ prod.price }}</p>
</div>

Попробуйте изменить атрибут href элемента a на product/{{ prod.id }} для корректного перехода на страницу карточки:
<a href="product/{{ prod.id }}" class="h3 text-decoration-none">{{ prod.title }}</a>


Спасибо большое за ответ, помогло!

Если вам помог мой ответ отметьте его как полезный пожалуйста, спасибо.
